# Is 'feeling' how gears down shift on automatic car indicate gearbox or clutch nearing it's end?

Tags: transmission, automatic-transmission, clutch

In my car (Cadillac CTS) gears used to shift seamlessly when not excessively accelerating, however recently I have noticed especially on lower gears when they are down shifting to actually 'feel' how it goes into lower gear (that sort of deceleration feeling when cogs connect).

**Does it mean that clutch or gearbox is about to die, or is it something else?**

Comment: Is engine brake the deceleration you describe?

Comment: @JoErNanO I think so - it's like on manual you would switch gear to lower and then release clutch immediately, it would give you this 'bump...' kinda feeling of gear connecting 'not nicely'.

Comment: It may indicate that it's time for a service.  Have your gearbox fluids and filters been replaced recently?

Comment: @SteveMatthews I had car serviced couple of months ago, not sure if they changed gearbox fluid, need to check....